# Matlab: how to use an array in dsolve function?

Tags: arrays, matlab, ode, dsolve

I have an ODE system of two equations, but want to minimize it with using just one equation with the result of the other.

1)

```
t=linspace(0,2,3);
syms x(t) y(t);
inits='x(0)=2,y(0)=0';
[x,y]=dsolve('Dx=y','Dy=(y*2)-x', inits)
```

x = 2*exp(t) - 2*t*exp(t);
    y = -2*t*exp(t)

```
xx=eval(vectorize(x));
```

xx = 2.0000; 0;  -14.7781

```
yy=eval(vectorize(y));
```

yy = 0;   -5.4366;  -29.5562

After I had got the results, I tried to solve it just with one equation and use xx array in Dy equation.

2)

```
inits='y(0)=0';
[y]=dsolve('Dy=(y*2)-xx', inits);
```

y = xx/2 - (xx*exp(2*t))/2

```
yy=eval(vectorize(y));
```

yy = 0;         0;  396.0397

The values are not the same as it was in the first example. How to get the same result using array?

Answer (score 1):

One problem seems to be that variable xx is not symbolic, so the symbolic solver appears to be considering it as a constant.

A bigger problem is that you really haven't identified how exactly you want matlab to treat the xx values as a continuous function, when it's merely a vector of three points! The fact that you are even expecting the output to be the same for the second case indicates some kind of misunderstanding to me.

But to make this definite, lets assume that you want it to treat xx as a ZOH (zero order held) continuous signal. To handle this symbolically I believe you would need to construct the ZOH signal explicitly using Heaviside functions.

Alternative you could solve it numerically using ode45 for example

```
t  = [0,1,2];
xx = [2, 0, -14.7781];
dydy = @(t,y) 2*y - xx(1+trunc(t));
y = ode45(dydt, [0,2], 0);
```

This will return yy values of **[0, -6.39, -47.21]** at the t values of **[0, 1, 2]** respectively.

This corresponds well with the theoretical values (calculated by hand) of **[0, 1-e^2, e^2-e^4]** for the ZOH system.

As you can see the above answer is much more in line with your original solution of yy = **[0, -5.4366, -29.5562]**. Naturally however the two systems differ, as the first one was fed with a continuous time exponential signal whereas the second system was fed with a very coarsely sampled approximation!

You make the two more similar by sampling at a faster rate (finer time interval), and also by interpolating the intersample points with something better than a ZOH.

Update:
*Thank you. Maybe can you help me with creating ZOH continuous signal? How to do that?*

In the above example I created a ZOH in my derivative function (dydx) by using the three given points in the xx vector and accessing these using "xx(1+trunc(t))". This uses trunc (truncate) to explicitly hold the input constant during the inter-sample (non integer) times.

Seeing as your ODE is linear, you could also use the matlab function "lsim()" which allows you to directly specify the time vector and input vector, and also to directly specify the type of input interpolation (including ZOH, which is actually the default).

For example:

```
t=[0,1,2]
x=[2,0,-2*e^2]
num=-1
den=[1,-2]
mytf = tf(num,den)
y = lsim(mytf,x,t,0,'zoh');
```

As with my previous ode45 numerical solution, this gives the identical solution of,

```
y = [0.00000; -6.38906; -47.20909]
```

Update (again)
*Thank you. Maybe can you help me with creating ZOH continuous signal? How to do that?*

Re the symbolic solver. I don't have access to the Matlab symbolic library, but if you really want to use the symbolic solver, then as I explained previous, you can construct a continuous time ZOH signal using the heaviside (unit step) function. Something like the following should do it:

```
syms xzoh(t)
xzoh = xx(1)*heaviside(t) + (xx(2)-xx(1))*heaviside(t-1) + (xx(3)-xx(2))*heaviside(t-2)
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe can you help me with creating ZOH continuous signal? How to do that?

Comment: Then I write mytf = tf(num,den) in Matlab, I get an error:
Undefined function 'tf' for input arguments of type 'double'

Comment: It should work. Take a look at the documentation for tf() here. http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/control/ref/tf.html

Comment: Also, what does your copy of matlab return if you type **help tf** at the command prompt?

Comment: Writes the documentation of function tf

Comment: I cant test it, I'm running octave. But the tf() function should work similarly for both Octave and Matlab. Can you confirm with *your* documentation that tf(num,den) is valid syntax.

Comment: Assuming that tf(num,den) **is** valid syntax on your version of matlab then double check that your num and den vectors are correct. num and den should be row vectors. Try typing them in directly instead of cut and paste and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Try typing **num=[0, -1]** and **den=[1, -2]** and see if that works with tf()

Comment: I reinstalled Matlab and function works well. It seems that it was something wrong with directories.

I also tried to solve that a bit differently.
I wrote the function: f = @(new_x) interp1(t,xx, new_x); It gives the exact results as xx vector. But when I add it to dsolve I get some errors.

     f = @(new_x) interp1(t,xx, new_x);
     [y]=dsolve('Dy=(y*2)-f', inits);
     yy=eval(vectorize(y));
"??? Error using ==> eval
Undefined function or method 'rdivide' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'."